# Remove GRUB Loader

Tags: ubuntu, windows-7

I have installed Ubuntu on my laptop and now I want to remove it and the Grub Loader. How I can do it without the Windows installation disk (I cannot use the Recovery Console).

Comment: This is really important. The first time I tried to do this I got an unbootable computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download a windows recovery disk to do this for you here:
http://neosmart.net/blog/2008/windows-vista-recovery-disc-download/ There's a disk available for Windows Vista and Windows 7.

Download, burn and boot it. Open up the recovery command prompt and execute the following:

```
Bootrec.exe /fixboot
Bootrec.exe /fixmbr
```

Then restart the computer and remove the linux partition from disk management in Windows and format the free space to NTFS.

Comment: Does this still work for Windows 10? Or is there a different way?