# Restore bootloader after Ubuntu has been installed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-8, grub, bootloader

I've installed Ubuntu. Windows doesn't boot anymore and doesn't appear in the GRUB menu. I've tried to install the Windows bootloader via recovery console from a Windows DVD as it's said [here](https://superuser.com/questions/157446/remove-grub-loader).

```
Bootrec.exe /fixboot
Bootrec.exe /fixmbr
```

Nothing happened, and GRUB keeps loading Ubuntu. Automatic repair from the Windows DVD failed (didn't give me a readable message, though). I've tried to edit `40_custom` script, but couldn't save any changes.

Is there a way to get my Windows back?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/a/602931/219655

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to use BootRepair, a utility which you can download either onto your install media, or directly onto your Ubuntu installation, if you can boot into it.

A detailed description of how to use it can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), I really could not do not any better than this guide. For most cases, the default set of actions, as shown in the guide, are absolutely sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this (in ubuntu):

- Open a terminal
- `sudo mount /dev/<windows partition>` you can find out what is the windows partition with
  `lsblk` based in his size.
- `sudo os-prober`
- `sudo update-grub`

I didn't try it myself, but should work. the answer is based on this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197868/grub-does-not-detect-windows)